# Convert wav to wma

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to convert a .wav file to .wma (or .mp3) on Windows Phone 7 Mango.

I want to save a recording from the microphone and use the SaveRingtoneTask so I can save it as a ringtone.

How can I convert the file on Windows Phone 7 so I don't have to use a web service?

If it can't be done on the phone does anyone know how to convert it and trim it down to 40 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx and stripping out everything but the .mp3 convertions.

Comment: can you share your project version ported to WP7?

Comment: The file is too large to post. Please send me your contact information and I'll email you it.

Comment: Just to be clear. this is not a port to wp7. Its a dll based on the about codeproject that strips out all the extra and made to a dll. then it's used in a web service.  I sent you the file via email you sent.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Windows Media Audio compressor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WmaCompressor.aspx).