# Convert a windows phone microphone to wma or mp3

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to convert a windows phone microphone to wma or mp3.

It looks like the question is answered here:
[Convert wav to wma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642314/convert-wav-to-wma)

But I don't understand how 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx
can be used since it uses a dll which doesn't run on the phone.

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify: The OP from the mentioned SO question coded a server-side solution, as the code in Code Project is a wrapper invoking the usual mp3lame dll. If there was a way to encode in WMA, that would probably be a part of Windows Foundation for Windows Phone, which unfortunately doesn't propose an encoder for WMA.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make it AUTOMATICALLY have a compressed file format. I'm not sure that is possible.

The examples shown through those links are for converting from .wav to .mp3 WHILE ON A COMPUTER.